# How to fix "tf.math.confusion_matrix()" error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to find the confusion matrix of a multiclass classification problem. I'm using tf.math.confusion_matrix() to do that. The code snippet is as follows,

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
Y_test = tf.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(Y_test, y_pred)
```

The output of `Y_test` is,

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 2 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 3 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 ... 0 0 0]], shape=(2124, 279), dtype=int64)
```

The output of `y_pred` is,

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 2 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 2 3 ... 0 0 0]
 [3 2 0 ... 3 1 3]
 ...
 [3 1 0 ... 2 3 2]
 [1 0 3 ... 1 1 2]
 [1 0 2 ... 1 1 2]], shape=(2124, 279), dtype=int64)
```

`Y_test[1]` looks like the following,

```
    tf.Tensor(
[0 2 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], shape=(279,), dtype=int64)
```

`y_pred[1]` looks like the following,

```
tf.Tensor(
[0 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 3 1 0 2 3 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 2 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 2 0 0 3 2 0 0 3 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 1 0 2 3 0 3
 3 0 2 3 1 3 2 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1
 0 3 0 3 3 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
 3 0 3 3 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 3 0 3 3 0 2 3 0 3 3
 3 3 3 0 3 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 3 0 0 3 0 0 0 3 0 2
 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 2 0 3 2 3 0 3 0 0 0], shape=(279,), dtype=int64)
```

And the error I'm getting is,

```
InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions [0,2) of indices[shape=[2124,2,279]] must match dimensions [0,2) of updates[shape=[2124,279]] [Op:ScatterNd]
```

How this can be solved?

Comment: Did you do the `print(Y_test)` before or after calling `argmax`? Because `Y_test` is defined **in** the argmax so, it looks like printed before, but according to its shape, it needs to be arg-maxed yet. Please, share all code in a single block (to avoid this kind of ambiguity), and don't need to print full tensors: just `print(Y_test.shape)` output is enough

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code of model to replicate the error along with the code section where this `InvalidArgumentError'  is showing.